# skrollr creates large gaps on page

Tags: jquery, parallax

I'm working on a site using [scrollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) and I get a problem with height issues as elements comes in. As a reference, I'm using the scripts found on [this template](http://themify.me/demo/themes/parallax/).

In the first screenshot, I get a large gap between my elements that fade in from both sides and the element below. However, in the second screenshot, you can see that everything is fixed when I refresh the page.

Screenshot 1
[image: Large gap between elements fading in from both sides and other elements]

Screen shot 2
[image: Everything is fixed when I refresh my page]

This is a recurring problem in Firefox (Mac/PC), Safari, Chrome (Mac/PC), and IE (10 and lower, untested on IE11, but having doubts the problem remains). All browsers are up to date (except IE).

---

### Files

For reference (and testing) purposes, I did try linking directly to the files used by the template mentioned above. This scripts have not been changed in my local files.

```
<script src="http://themify.me/demo/themes/parallax/wp-content/themes/parallax/js/skrollr.js?ver=3.6.1"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://themify.me/demo/themes/parallax/wp-content/themes/parallax/js/themify.script.js?ver=3.6.1'></script>
<script>skrollr.init({mobileCheck: function(){return false;}});</script>
```

#### Attempts

- Loading the init on `window.load` and on `document.ready` -> No change
- Refreshing the page via jQuery, meta refresh and refreshing only the div -> No change
- Tried using the `src` directly from the template on Themify -> No change
- Calling any other script after this has been processed -> No change
- Resizing the window -> corrects the issue, but asking people to resize the window doesn't make any sense
- {forceHeight: false} option

---

### What I've noticed

I've realized that on a page where I have more elements using this effect, the gap seems to get smaller. This is somewhat annoying since this would mean the script itself works, but needs more height on my page.

My div code :

```
<article style="left: 0px; top: 0px; opacity: 1;"
data-bottom-top="left[sqrt]: -400px;top[sqrt]:200px;opacity: 0;"
data-center-top="left[sqrt]:0px;top[sqrt]:0px;opacity:1;"
class="highlight type-highlight post col2-2 skrollable skrollable-after">
    <figure class="post-image">
        <img src="imges/picture1.jpg" />
    </figure>
</article>
<article style="right: 0px; top: 0px; opacity: 1;"
data-bottom-top="right[sqrt]:-200px;top[sqrt]:200px;opacity:0;" 
data-center-top="right[sqrt]:0px;top[sqrt]:0px;opacity: 1;" 
class="highlight type-highlight post col2-2 skrollable skrollable-after">
    <div class="post-content">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ullamcorper justo at sollicitudin posuere. Nulla elementum, turpis vel posuere egestas, nisi diam malesuada arcu, eu pulvinar nunc mi vitae odio. Aliquam semper eros nec quam tempor, vitae ultrices turpis posuere. Aliquam mi massa, imperdiet at diam nec, volutpat vulputate dolor. Curabitur condimentum dolor tortor, at laoreet risus condimentum a. Mauris lobortis ut magna nec egestas. Etiam at accumsan est. Donec gravida scelerisque lorem sit amet vestibulum.
        </p>
    </div>
</article>
```

And, from testing, smaller pages don't allow for `top[sqrt]:200px;`; this value must be smaller (in some cases, 0, making the effect only left/right as opposed to coming in on an angle as well, which was what originally caught my attention).

Comment: when do you call `init`? Try calling it later (e.g. on window `load`) or call `refresh` on window load. It's probably because images aren't loaded when you init skrollr.

Comment: The function _is_ called onLoad, it is the second to last item on my page (last one being Google Analytics) and still changes nothing. I've tried also tried refreshing the div and the page through jQuery, but no success.

Comment: What happens if you resize the browser instead of refreshing? Does the gap disappear?

Comment: Yes, the gap does disappear. Does that change anything?

Comment: It does some refreshing inside of skrollr. Please post some of your code. Maybe we mean something different with "onload".

Comment: Please view the edits to the post; I've added the source to the original file and some of the things I've tested so far along with their respective outcomes.

Comment: Does it work if you execute `skrollr.get().refresh()` in the console? Without having your actual page available somewhere I can't help you any further.

Comment: No, @Prinzhorn, I get : `ReferenceError: skrollr is not defined`, but the script essentially works as I do get the sliding effects to work.

Comment: I've been through this before, most probably the skrollr data values that are used to calculate the position of items while scrolling are a bit off. the full code with the actual page will be very helpful though.

Comment: on a second note, and also since i've worked extensively on skrollr, try adding {forceHeight: false} to your options

Comment: @Kheu, this has not done it for me.

Comment: Please view the `What I've noticed` section just added. Perhaps this should be reviewed by the people working on the code, but I think this pretty much locates the issue. However, it _would_ be interesting for the original effect (`data-bottom-top` value of `200px`) to be reviewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with the script, I've come to conclude:

- The more items using the script on the page, the better it works;
- On pages with less items using the script, the `top[sqrt]:200px;` value must be smaller, sometimes even at `0` to allow for left/right fades only, but nothing coming in. Values too big for the page cause large gaps, thus reducing the impact of the effect.

Playing with those two points have successfully eliminated the gaps on the page.

However, after having played with the script, I do think there is something interesting to it, but I am uncertain if I prefer CSS3 with maybe a lazyload or something of the sort.

Answer (score 2):

As you have the default values set you will be using forceHeight: true.
This means skrollr calculates how much vertical scroll you need to complete all animations. This often causes confusion as if your final animation moves an element offscreen it needs to add enough scroll to complete that - this often leaves an empty space at the bottom.

Alternatively, if you resize your browser window once the page has loaded skrollr tries to recalculate the max scroll amount, if the height of elements are changed with JavaScript during this reflow it can also leave a gap at the bottom.

Inside a resize listener you can add:

```
skrollr.get().refresh();
```